# Can't find unexpected operator (Bash error)

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I've created a simple Bash script that should create symlinks in /usr/local/{etc,lib,include...} from an inputted directory path

```
#!/bin/sh

input="$1"
for subdir in "etc include bin lib man share sbin"; do
   dir=$input/$subdir
   if [ -e $dir ] && [ -d $dir ]; then
      for file in $dir/*; do
         ln -s $file /usr/local/$subdir
      done
   fi
done
```

The error i'm getting is:

```
user@comp:/usr/local# ./update-locallinks /usr/local/test/
[: 6: /usr/local/test/etc: unexpected operator
```

and this is what /usr/local/test/ looks like:

```
user@comp:/usr/local# ls /usr/local/test/
bin
etc
include
lib
```

Comment: I'm not sure but try dir="$input/$subdir" instead of dir=$input/$subdir

Comment: add a `set -x` to the second line and paste the output

Comment: @Troydm, I tried that with no avail, but thanks anyways!

Comment: BTW, the fact that this isn't a [mcve] but has a bunch of code unrelated to the question included means I can't point someone else with the same immediate problem at it without asking them to dig through all the bits that aren't relevant to the problem itself. In the future, please try to make the code contained in questions the shortest possible sample that produces the same bug.

Comment: (also, this shell isn't actually bash; `/bin/sh` is POSIX sh -- even if it's linked to the bash shell, it runs in compatibility mode when called under the `sh` name and doesn't offer the full `bash` language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always protect your bash variables with double quotes in test expressions:

```
   if [ -e "$dir" ] && [ -d "$dir" ]; then
```

Comment: -e is unnecessary, `if [ -d "$dir" ]; then` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
for subdir in "etc include bin lib man share sbin"; do
```

Why the quotes? Change that to:

```
for subdir in etc include bin lib man share sbin; do
```

otherwise `$dir` will contain `etc include bin ...` on the first (and only) iteration.

Comment: Though this didn't solve that error "unexpected operator" this would have been my next error, so thanks! this DID help!

Comment: @xenagi: it does solve that error too, unless you input a path that has spaces in it in which case your `ln` call will fail too (even if you quoted the vars in the test expressions)