# "[: OS: unexpected operator" error in shell

Tags: shell, ubuntu, terminal

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "List of file which have read ,write and executable permissions in the current directory are: "

for file in *    
do
  if  [ -r $file -a -w $file -a -x $file ]
  then
    echo $file
  fi
done
```

Why it is showing error like this:

```
os1f.sh: 6: [: OS: unexpected operator
```

Comment: Try by using #!/bin/bash as a shebang

Comment: You probably have files with spaces in their names. You have to quote the expansions: `"$file"` everywhere.

Comment: Also, using `-a` is marked deprecated by POSIX: you should use `[ ... ] && [ ... ]` instead of `[ ... -a ... ]`.

Comment: Ugh. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086793/cant-find-unexpected-operator-bash-error is the same problem, but it's such a badly-written question that I hate to close this as a duplicate of it. (Edit: Cleaned the other up, so I think it's clearer now).

Comment: @kometonja, switching to bash would only help here if the OP also changed their code to use `[[ ... ]]` -- and they'd need to change from `-a` to `&&` at the same time.